# Using google apps openID on a site (not market place)

Tags: openid, google-apps

I am working on a site an want to use google apps openid as the target audience will all have open id from google apps; however I am having trouble installing the php-openid-apps-discovery add on.  I'm no dead set on using a php library but thats what have been trying so far.  My question is if anyone knows of any good tutorials or alternate libraries that support google apps openid.

ps: google has not been very useful so far

Answer (score 0):

Any OpenID library will work with Google's implementation of OpenID. Take your pick:

http://wiki.openid.net/w/page/12995176/Libraries

Comment: thanks for the reply. google apps (not to be confused with google itself) uses a diffrent method for discovery then the standard openid that is why php-openid requires the php-openid-apps-discovery addon. only select libraries support this alternate method.